# PostgreSQL's XMIN in Oracle & MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql

I'm trying to get the equivalent for this code on Oracle & MySQL

```
if(vardbtype.equals("POSTGRESQL")){
            Long previousTxId = 0L;
            Long nextTxId = 0L;

            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            System.out.println("----------------------------");

            try(Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/"+ vardbserver, vardbuser, vardbpassword);
                 PreparedStatement stmts = c.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM "+ vardbname +" where xmin::varchar::bigint > ? and xmin::varchar::bigint < ? ");
                 PreparedStatement max = c.prepareStatement("select max(xmin::varchar::bigint) as txid from "+ vardbname)
                ) {
                c.setAutoCommit(false);

                while(true) {
                    stmts.clearParameters();

                    try(ResultSet rss = max.executeQuery()) {
                        if(rss.next()) {
                            nextTxId = rss.getLong(1);
                        }
                    }
                    stmts.setLong(1, previousTxId);
                    stmts.setLong(2, nextTxId + 1);
                    try(ResultSet rss = stmts.executeQuery()) {
                        while(rss.next()) {
                            String message = rss.getString("MESSAGE");
                            System.out.println("Message = " + message);
                            TextMessage mssg = session.createTextMessage(message);
                            System.out.println("Sent: " + mssg.getText());
                            producer.send(mssg);
                        }
                        previousTxId = nextTxId;
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(batchperiod2);
                }
            }
        }
```

Basically, the code works to get contents inside a database's table and sent it to ActiveMQ. And when the table updated, it will sent the content that just updated (not sending the past that was sent). But this code only works on PostgreSQL

Then i'm planning to create an "if" function. So i can use another database to getting the data (Oracle and MySQL).

I guess i must change this code right?

```
 try(Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/"+ vardbserver, vardbuser, vardbpassword);
             PreparedStatement stmts = c.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM "+ vardbname +" where xmin::varchar::bigint > ? and xmin::varchar::bigint < ? ");
             PreparedStatement max = c.prepareStatement("select max(xmin::varchar::bigint) as txid from "+ vardbname)
            ) {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple thoughts supplemental to Thorsten's answer.

First, `xmin` is a system column which is, iirc, stored in the row header on disk.  It is updated by writes.  I have not yet run into a case where the transaction id's don't increase.  However, there has to be some wraparound point.  I think you are better off with a trigger which stores the transaction ids in another table for processing for this reason (and using that to process things).

For Oracle and MySQL, underlying storage is sufficiently different that I don't see how you can do this directly.

If you want a common solution you want a queue table where you can use a trigger to insert waiting copies, and then select/delete from that in your worker.  This will likely work better on MySQL than on PostgreSQL, and for Oracle you want to look for index-oriented tables.  If autovacuum has trouble keeping up, ask more questions or hire a consultant.

**After further research**

InnoDB provides a `DB_TRX_ID` column which is similar.  Note you *cannot* assume you have this column if you are running MySQL because MySQL has different table storage engines and not all even support transactions.  So that is an important limitation.

I was unable to locate a similar column on Oracle.

Comment: Honestly i got this task from my lecture :|

Comment: Do a deep dive into the storage of MySQL and Oracle.  I don't actually think it is possible with InnoDB or index oriented tables in Oracle.  It might be possible in heap tables otherwise because in heap tables the db has to have some way of finding out what rows are visible.

Comment: Basically i want to get every row in a table that only have 1 column. but if the table updated, it get the row that only updated...

Comment: On MySQL I was able to find a column when using InnodB.  Not sure about Oracle.  You will want to do a deep dive into how they handle multiversioning.

Answer (score 1):

This script is looking in intervals at a table and putting out all inserted messages since that last loop.

PostgreSQL stores the transaction number that inserted a record, so this can be used to find the newly inserted records (although I am not sure whether it is guaranteed for a new transaction to have a higher number than all previous ones as the script assumes).

Other DBMS don't have this pseudo column. So you would have to have a timestamp column in your table and use this instead. You'd have to change the two queries as well as the code to match the data type (I suppose `java.sql.Timestamp` instead of `Long`, but I am no Java guy).

Comment: Thankyou for the respon btw, in this case i only have 1 column that will be selecting the content inside every row, it haven't the time stamp column...

Comment: What I am saying is: you must create one. Otherwise you'd have no indication for what's new and what's old.

Comment: Hmm... i got the table from my lecture, so i cant add it :/ Btw i got some reference, is the row id on oracle works same as the xmin? it create a pseudocolumn too right?

Comment: Both are pseudo columns. Postgre's `XMIN` stores the inserting transaction number; it is thus a fixed value for a row that cannot change. The script assumes this to increment (and I don't know if that assumption is valid) and builds up on this assumption. Oracle's `ROWID` stores a row's physical location. This is not fixed, but can change when a row gets re-located.

Comment: So: You need some column to indicate insertion order. One would usually use a timestamp column for this. An incrementing ID would also be possible (as from an Oracle sequence). I don't even know if the script's assumption on `XMIN` is correct. Anyway, Oracle and other DBMS don't have such a column anyway, so you must create one. If you cannot, then you'd have to have an array of all records in your script and compare them to all records in the table with each loop, which is out of question I think. So if you cannot add a column you need a *completely* different approach.

Comment: As mentioned, if insertion order is important for you than you must change the table and add an according column. In your case, however, insertion order may not be important. All you want to be informed of is new inserts. You'd typically use a trigger and a log table for this. Everytime a record gets inserted, the trigger creates a log record. The script then reads the log, outputs the data and deletes the log entry.